# ¿Cómo pongo color de fondo en un checkbox?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Me gustaría que me ayudaran para poder ponerle color de fondo a el input.
HTML

```
<label class="myCheckbox"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></label><span class="id">{{row.id}}</span>
```

CSS

```
.myCheckbox input:checked{
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

Comment: Mas que darte una solucíon especifica te recomiendo que visites el siguiente [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp) donde muestra como puedes dar estilo a un checkbox y a un radio.

Answer (score 1):

Un checkbox no tiene la propiedad `background-color` de por sí, pero podrías usar este snippet para llegar a  lograr lo que deseas. Espero te sirva.

```css
.checkbox {
  margin: 0 0 1em 2em;
}
.checkbox .tag {
  color: #595959;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
}
.checkbox label {
  display: inline;
}
.checkbox .input-assumpte {
  display: none;
}
.input-assumpte + label:after {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #cacece;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: inline-block;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  content: '';
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.input-assumpte:checked + label:after {
  background-color: #595959;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input-assumpte" id="input-confidencial" />
  <label for="input-confidencial">Opción</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No es posible (al menos hasta ahora) darle un color de fondo "directamente" al checkbox, pero hay varias soluciones disponibles con solo CSS (generalmente se le da estilo al label que acompaña), la siguiente es una de mis preferidas:

```css
.squaredThree {
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.squaredThree label {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#222222), to(#45484d));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222 0%, #45484d 100%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
          box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.squaredThree label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.squaredThree label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.squaredThree input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="squaredThree">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree" name="check" checked />
      <label for="squaredThree"></label>
    </div>
```