# Modificar background-color input checkbox

Tags: html, css, backgroundworker

Tengo este checkbox:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <div fxLayout="row" class="content_check">
          <div fxLayout="row">
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
              <label>He vist l'evidència de la informació </label>
          </div>
 </div>
```

Y me gustaria poder modificar el estilo del check para tener un fondo naranja cuando este en "check":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Directamente no se puede realizar, debido que a es un componente que cada navegador los renderiza de una manera. Pero puedes "trampearlo" de una manera similar a esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/153258/41639

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con css, aunque no se cambia directamente el color del input si no el del span/div visible, tienes una guía muy sencilla en [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)